# Matrix multiplication with integers or doubles in data table

Tags: r, data.table

Can someone explain to me why this works:

```
a <- data.table(t(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
b <- matrix(data=1, nrow=10, ncol=5)
a[,lapply(.SD,function(x)(x*b[,x]))]
```

But this doesn't:

```
a <- data.table(t(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)))
b <- matrix(data=1, nrow=10, ncol=5)
a[,lapply(.SD,function(x)(x*b[,x]))]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the column values of 'a' act as column index to subset the 'b', while in the second case it wont because the values are 0.1 to 0.5.  So, instead of looping through the columns, loop through the sequence of the columns, and then subset the 'b' and the column values, which would work in both cases

```
a[, lapply(seq_along(.SD),function(x)(.SD[[x]]*b[,x]))]
```

---

Or just replicate the rows of 'a' and then multiply with 'b'

```
a[rep(seq_len(.N), nrow(b))] * b
```

Comment: Thanks, as my actual matrix has 100000 columns and 200 rows, I needed an efficient method. Therefore I am using the features of datatable and not your second proposed solution.

Comment: @Z117  Not a problem.